# plotting scatter plot by weeks of days in python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have simpe dataset in a dataframe in which year, attendance, weeks are the column.

```
attendance    week      years

37440         Sun       2010-04-04
43504         Mon       2010-04-05
38935         Mon       2010-04-05
40052         Mon       2010-04-05
43510         Tue       2010-04-06
38000         Tue       2010-04-06
10090         Tue       2010-04-06
41533         Wed       2010-04-07
```

i would like to plot a scatter,i have many values of attancdance against each day i would like to average them and show them on scatter plot. 
i saw this on other post and i tried but it gave an error here is my code

```
import pandas as pd

days=['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
log_2010=pd.read_excel('GL2010-2017.xlsx')

year=log_2010['years']
attendance=log_2010['attendace']
week=log_2010['day_of_week']
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'years':year,
       'attendance':attendance,
       'week':week
    })
new_df=df.dropna(how='any')
new_df['years']=pd.to_datetime(year,format='%Y%m%d')
df['week'] = pd.Categorical(new_df['week'], categories=days)


df[['week', 'attendance']].groupby('week').mean().plot.scatter(df['week'],df['attendance'])
```

i get this error
*KeyError: "['Sun' 'Mon' 'Mon' ... 'Sun' 'Sun' 'Sun'] not in index"*

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: this is the complete error message.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set up week as index when you import data from excel file: log_2010=pd.read_excel('GL2010-2017.xlsx', index_col='week')

Comment: it gives this error: ValueError: Index week invalid